Remove ► from our site-specific line about spoilers in "How to Format"
The "How to Format" box previously used ► characters to imitate list formatting. So when we got a site-specific line about spoiler markup in 2016, it had one of those characters:

► mark spoilers by placing >! at start of line

The ► were removed in 2022, and now it uses true <li> list markup. (Incidentally, that fixed a 2017 Meta Puzzling SE feature-request). However, our ► wasn't removed in the network-wide change. This means our "How to Format" box looks quite odd:

How to Format

► mark spoilers by placing >! at start of line
create code fences with backticks ` or tildes ~
like so



[...]

Compare to the Math Educators SE one:

How to Format

create code fences with backticks ` or tildes ~
like so



[...]

Please remove the ► from our line about spoilers.
